# Using something other than ID in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list

I have two models, Book and Chapter.

I would like chapters to be accessed by their order in the book rather that their id's

> /Books/the-chapter-title/chapters/1

Would it be recommended to do this as I would like to also have the ability to reorder the chapters.

I would like the chapter numbers to move up and down the list using `acts-as-list` but also access them via their pecking order.

Comment: I was just worried my code might fall over itself in doing this.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a `to_params` method in your model if you want to use something other than id, but this usually leads to headaches

check out https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: so I could access chapters via a route that looks like this `/chapters/the-book-title-1`?

Comment: Exactly. You can put everything you want instead of ID.